# duplicate entry on using commerce_product_ui_product_type_save()?

Tags: commerce

Reference to the code https://www.drupal.org/node/1059624#comment-4083864

```
 $product_type = commerce_product_ui_product_type_new();

  $product_type['type'] = 'prestation';
  $product_type['name'] = t('Prestation');
  $product_type['description'] = t('A basic prestation.');
  $product_type['is_new'] = TRUE;

  commerce_product_ui_product_type_save($product_type, FALSE);
```

When I execute the folllowing code given above I get a

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062
>   Duplicate entry 'prestation' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO
>   {commerce_product_type} (type, name, description, help, revision)
>   VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] =>
>   abcs_new15 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => abcs new15
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => abcs new15 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7239
>   of

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are setting `$product_type['is_new']` to `TRUE`, which is saying to the module the product type is new, but that evidently is not true. That is what the error is telling you.

Set `$product_type['is_new']` to `FALSE`, or don't set it at all, and you will not get any error.

If you are programmatically creating new product types, be sure you give to `$product_type['type']` a unique value for each of the product types you create.

#### Reference

- [`commerce_product_ui_product_type_save()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!product!commerce_product_ui.module/function/commerce_product_ui_product_type_save/7)

Comment: I am giving a unique value to $product_type['type']

Comment: also $product_type['new'] = TRUE since I need to add a new product type programmatically

Comment: You are clearly using for `$product_type['type']` a value that is already present in the table used by the module, or the database engine would not return an error saying "Duplicate entry 'prestation'."